# What is the definition of asymptotically flat convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, control-theory, uniform-continuity

I'm reading an article about a sliding modes control approach which mentions that a given function Ln(cosh(*)) is nearly linear outside the small neighborhood of the origin but partial asymptotically flat near zero.

I'm not quite sure what does "partially flat" means, I thought it might be a reference to a certain kind of convergence rate or maybe the smoothness of the function. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I suspect this was intended to be a loose description of the behavior instead of a precise mathematical condition. The function itself and its first derivative are $0$ at the origin, but the second derivative is $1$. You can see what it looks like by entering $y=\ln(\cosh x)$ into the [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Comment: Yeah, looks like that. Thank you.